# How do I make an action repeat in VBS if you press yes?

Tags: vbscript

I am working on this program called 8ball where if you press ok at the start, it gives you a random magic 8 ball answer. afterwards there is a screen that says, wanna go again? with yes and no buttons. i wanna make it so that if I press yes, it repeats the action where an answer is chosen. (and for no it just closes) i'm new to vbs and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
result = MsgBox ("Your Text",vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BoxName")
Select Case result
    Case 6
        'Case 6 happens if the User choose yes.
        'If you wrote a function for your question fill it in here 
    Case 7
        'Case 7 happens if the User choose NO
End Select
```

Without seeing your Code this is the only answer that comes to my mind. Maybe it will solve your Problem.